# MongoDB: Must every index be prefixed with the shardkey

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, sharding

Imaging we have documents like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(""),
  accountId: ObjectId(""),
  userId: ObjectId(""),
  someOtherFieldA: ["some", "array", "values"],
  someOtherFieldB: ["other", "array", "values"],
  ...
}
```

Furthermore there are multiple compound indices, ex.:

```
{ userId: 1, someOtherFieldA: 1, ... }
{ userId: 1, someOtherFieldB: 1, ... }
```

We want to shard by `accountId`.

Would it be enough to add a single field index for `accountId`, so that the existing indices still work? Or would all indices need the `accountId` as prefix (first part)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the `sh.shardCollection()` command then MongoDB automatically creates an index on the shard key field (unless such an index exist already), so you don't need to care about this question.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. So the following query: `find { accountId: ObjectId(""), userId: ObjectId(""), someOtherFieldA: "some" }, projection { _id: 0, userId: 1, someOtherFieldA: 1 }` would still be fully covered?

Comment: Of course, `accountId: ObjectId("")` determines which shard will by actually queried. On the shard itself, the other indexes are used. MonogDB is also able to use several indexes in one query.

Comment: This was my assumption. Thanks for the confirmation.